# PDF overview links not working inside my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, pdf, pdf.js

My web application used PDF.js to load PDFs in the browser. It gets the PDFs from a REST API.

The web app is a single page angularjs affair. You can navigate inside the app and open up one of these PDFs. When you do open one of them, the relative links to other PDFs inside the Outline of the first PDF do not work.

When I access the REST API URL at say, `api.example.com/rest/my-pdf.pdf`, with firefox (which used PDF.js to render PDFs), the PDF opens and the Outline has the correct relative links.

I suspect that it has something to do with my app being on a different origin than the PDF serving  REST API.

Each `OutlineItem` has an action dictionary with my relative links in there. The action dictionary has an ActionType (S) of `Launch` and a FileStream (F) value shown below.

[image: PDF Object browser]

I'm using the PDF.js viewer.html file to view PDFs.
This is done by creating an iframe like so:

```
<iframe src="/path/to/pdfjs/viewer.html?file=http://api.example.com/rest/my-pdf.pdf">
```

How can I get relative links working here?

P.S. I've scratched out only the actual filenames in red. I've left the path as is if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the links in the PDF outline were the "Launch ActionType".
PDF.js can't actually handle "Launch" types because it cannot launch external programs, seeing as it runs in a browser.

So, what PDF.js does is it pretends that the "Launch" type is a "GoToR ActionType" (Go To Remote).
This will work if the URL that the PDF is loaded from is the origin that PDF.js is also loaded from.

If this is not the case, like in my app (where PDF.js is loaded in an iframe inside an angular app), PDF.js is unable to resolve the URLs and so it leaves the links blank.

1. Section 8.5 of the [PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf) contains information on `Action`s in PDFs.
2. PDF.js [source file](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/5517c94d66f22cc98df6dd1dab90ced15d49f3b8/src/core/obj.js#L934) shows how different `ActionType`s are processed.

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
onclick=" window.open('../../assets/python/python.pdf'); return true;"
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I'm loading the PDF in an iframe and not as a link. Where would I attach the onclick handler?